TRegistry GetKeyNames not working as expected
I am trying to use the following code to get a list of subkeys in the registry. GetKeyNames takes a TString object. Upon return, the TStringList object has a count of 3 which is the correct count. However, while the TStringList has the proper count, it doesn't seem to have the names. This is probably something simple, but I haven't been able to discover the problem.
TRegistry *pRegistry = new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
pRegistry->RootKey   = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
pRegistry->OpenKeyReadOnly(L"\\SOFTWARE\\Ogre\\Fasthole");

TStringList *subkeyNames = new TStringList();
pRegistry->GetKeyNames(subkeyNames);

UnicodeString ALICE  = subkeyNames->Names[0];

ALICE is always NULL.

UPDATE:
The project being modified was originally developed with C++Builder 12.1 Athens.  I updated that project to 12.2 by creating a new project and adding all of the original forms to it. I still get the same result. I kept working on it and found the following:
TStringList *subkeys = new TStringList(); 
pRegistry->GetKeyNames(subkeys); 
UnicodeString RALPH = subkeys->Strings[0]; <--- this fails 
UnicodeString ALICE = subkeys->Strings[1][1]; <--- this also fails 
wchar_t NORTON = subkeys->Strings[0][1]; <--- this works 
wchar_t TRIXIE = RALPH[1]; <--- this also worked!!! 

If I try to use any of the UnicodeStrings, I get NULL values.
Since I'm working with single character keys, I can work around it, but it's certainly not right.

@3CxEZiVlQ that is true in pure C++, but this code is in a mixed C++/Delphi environment. TStringList and TRegistry both derive from Delphi's TObject class, and all Pascal-style TObject - based classes MUST be dynamically allocated. They won't work correctly the way you have shown, even though the C++ syntax is correct.

@3CxEZiVlQ No. Standard C++ smart pointers will work fine with such classes. But, smart pointers are about lifetime management, and this is not a lifetime management issue, it is a memory management issue. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2459_Delphi_style_classes_must_be_constructed_using_operator_new_(C%2B%2B)

Using 12.2, I cannot reproduce the issue you describe in your update. GetKeyNames() populates the TStringList correctly, and using its Strings[] property returns the full strings, as expected. There are no NULL values. You are just going to have to debug your project to find out what is really going on behind the scenes. I will say this, though - If UnicodeString RALPH = subkeys->Strings[0]; fails but then wchar_t TRIXIE = RALPH[1]; succeeds, then that is undefined behavior and you have bigger problems to worry about.

You need to use the TStringList's Strings[] property instead of its Names[] property:
//UnicodeString ALICE  = subkeyNames->Names[0];
UnicodeString ALICE  = subkeyNames->Strings[0];

TRegistry::GetKeyNames() returns the key names as-is, not in "name=value" format, which is why the Names[] property is returning a blank string - there is no name for it to return:

When the list of strings for the TStrings object includes strings that are name-value pairs, read Names to access the name part of a string. Names is the name part of the string at Index, where 0 is the first string, 1 is the second string, and so on. If the string is not a name-value pair, Names contains an empty string.


I tried that too. It failed. However, I moved the code into a small test application and it works just fine. There is something in my primary application that causing an issue. I checked the code and it matches line for line. It must be a compiler setting or something similar. It's very frustrating. Thank you for your input.

@Kevin there is no compiler setting that would cause the TStringList to be non-empty but contain blank strings. There has to be something else going on, probably another bug in your code somewhere that is causing side effects in this code. You are just going to have to debug it. Start by turning on Debug DCUs in your project settings so you can step into the actual source code for TStringList and TRegistry to see what is really going on internally

I did a bit more testing. The code works in a brandy new project but not this older one. It was created under Athena 12.1. I recently upgraded to 12.2. I always had to update my projects for prior upgrades. I didn’t this time and things appeared to work but I now question that assumption. I’m going to create a new project and add all of the forms to it. That may well cure this odd behavior.
